# How to check my Cisco Switch and router

Tags: router

I have bought a Cisco  refurbished router and Switch how to check it's all OK to use ? any commands ?

Comment: Generally if there are no errors on bootup, you should be good to go.

Comment: and what if i want to keep the logs of the bootup ? Is there anyway so that the logs generated on bootup saves automatically in a log server ?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, as most of boot logs are displayed before logging systems initializes.

Comment: Most serial terminal software has a logging option that puts everything received into a file ... if you want to save original boot messages the simplest way is usually connect to console and save the output.

Comment: If there are SFP, SFP+ or QSFP+ slots on that switch or router, be sure to (visually) inspect the connectors in the back of the slot, and be sure to check ALL of these slots with a known-to-be-good module and/or cable.  

I'm currently through 640 of 1088 ports of 17 'refurbished'  40G-Switches (64ports each), and my fingers are raw from un/replugging the QSFP modules and DirectAttachCables. The number of bent connector pins is frighteningly high :-(